# Set variable in mysql sql:query

Tags: mysql

I have a `SET` variables followed by a `SELECT` which works fine with MySQL until I attempt this wrapped in a Java query sql:query (which then indicates a syntax error on `SET). I removed the chevrons around the sql:query statement so you can see it.

```
sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/logs"

SET @locationID=0, @ts=NULL, @changed=0;

SELECT 
L4.assetid, etc etc
```

Is there a different command to SET variables for sql:query or do I need to set these variables beforehand, outside of sql:query?

Comment: Rather than editing the code to avoid it being read as HTML, just click the `{}` button in the editor toolbar, which formats it as source code.